# Is there a way to enable the "reduce blur" VR mode outside of VR?

Tags: applications, root-access

I haven't been able to find out anything about this setting outside of vr.

It's fine if this method requires root. Ideally this would be enabled by my app, though it's fine if I can enable it globally too.